# Django unittest POST form with image

Tags: python, django, testing, post

I am doing a Django Unittesting on Django REST ViewSets.
In one endpoint it can receive fields and image.
Here is `models.py`

```
class CarData(AbstractSoftModelController):
    front_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=RandomFileName('upload/cars'),
                                    blank=True,
                                    verbose_name=_('Front photo'))
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True, verbose_name=_('Brand'))
    model = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True, verbose_name=_('Model'))
    color = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                             blank=True,
                             db_index=True,
                             verbose_name=_('Color'))
```

`viewsets.py`

```
class CarDataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CarDataSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    filter_class = CarDataFilter
    queryset = CarData.objects.filter(license_plate__alive=True, license_plate__isnull=False)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class CarDataSerializer(ModelControllerSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CarData
        exclude = EXCLUDE_COMMON_FIELDS
        extra_kwargs = {
        }
```

And I want to test `POST` to this endpoint with image.

```
class CarDataViewSetTestCase(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        mommy.make(User, _quantity=1, username='sivabudh')
        mommy.make(CarData, _quantity=3,
                   brand='Ferrari',
                   color='black')
        mommy.make(LicensePlate, _quantity=3)
        self.client.force_login((User.objects.get(username='sivabudh')))

    def test_create(self):
        file_path = str(settings.ROOT_DIR.path('static_files/images/logo-eneos.png'))
        with open(file_path, "r", encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as fp:
            data = {
                'brand': 'Ferrari',
                'model': 'LaFerrari Aperta',
                'color': 'Red',
                'license_plate': LicensePlate.objects.first().id,
                'front_photo': fp
            }
            response = self.client.post(
                reverse('api:car-list'),
                data,
                content_type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            )
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        assert 200 == response.status_code
```

And the error is:

```
(Pdb) response.data
["{'brand': ['This field is required.'], 'model': ['This field is required.'], 'license_plate': ['This field is required.']}"]
```

**My attempts:**
Then I change the header a bit
`content_type='multipart/form-data'` 
I got `{'detail': 'Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None'}`

Where am I wrong?